# Running a custom daemon on start up

Tags: raspberry-pi, startup, daemon

I've got a small project that's based around a raspberry pi. A central part of this project is for my program to be executed on start-up and run until shutdown, all while running stand-alone (that means no SSH). One way I've found is to run my program with `nohup`, but this still requires an ssh session to start.

I've written the program following the guidelines for creating a linux daemon, yet when I execute it as `sudo ./myprogram`, it doesn't actually seem to be running as root (it can't to write to the GPIO pins). What is the proper way of going about this?

Comment: What Linux distribution are you running on your Raspberry Pi? (Raspbian?) That information might be helpful in figuring out what to do... Your system should have a set of init scripts that run during boot (for instance, look for an `/etc/init.d` directory.) That's usually the proper place to configure scripts to launch daemons on start up.

Comment: Yes, it's the latest version of raspbian. I took a look at that directory but am not sure how to make my own. Is it enough to just do `DAEMON=/usr/bin/myDaemon` and place my daemon executable in `/usr/bin/`?

Comment: Please state the version you are using, "The latest one" is changing over time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use systemd services to get this job done. It's easier to control your application via systemd have a look at this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files

Comment: Welcome to unix stackexchange and thanks for your reply. While providing sources is always good, it would really help if you could provide an example, links can break.